# org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: jbossHome 'null' must exist

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I'm getting

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.ConfigurationException: jbossHome 'null' must exist
```

when I try to run my Arquillian test from maven. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to point the required property in arquillian.xml.
For instance in my arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

   <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

   <container qualifier="jboss" default="true">
       <configuration>
           <property name="jbossHome">c:\dev\jboss-eap-6.3\</property>
           <property name="serverConfig">standalone-test.xml</property>
           <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5505,server=y,suspend=n -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</property>
       </configuration>
   </container>
</arquillian>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable pointing to your Jboss/EAP server before running your integration tests. You do it either from command line:

```
set JBOSS_HOME=c:\jboss-eap-6.4 (on Windows)
export JBOSS_HOME=/home/jboss-eap-6.4 (on Linux)
```

or set in your pom.xml file:

```
<build><plugins><plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <JBOSS_HOME>c:\jboss-eap-6.4</JBOSS_HOME>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin></plugins></build>
```